# DOMDocument to extract part of a webpage (Any encoding)?

Tags: php, html-parsing

What's the code to store in a string the whole webpage's content between `<body></body>` tags?

- can be any HTML/XHTML page
- can be any encoding (ISOx, UTF-8, Asian-something)
- can have attributes in the `<body>` (may trick the parser)

I've heard about DOMDocument but I'm a big rookie, some code sample would help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm)  solves the problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
$d = new DOMDOcument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$d->loadHTMLFile("http://stackoverflow.com");
$b = $d->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0);
if ($b !== null) {
    echo simplexml_import_dom($b)->asXML();
}
```

This will also include the `<body>` tag, and the content will have been modified to be well-formed XML.

To have no body tags (though now we don't have a single root, thus not well-formed XML):

```
$d = new DOMDOcument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$d->loadHTMLFile("http://stackoverflow.com");
$b = $d->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0);
if ($b !== null) {
    for ($n = $b->firstChild; $n !== null; $n = $n->nextSibling) {
        echo simplexml_import_dom($n)->asXML();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about stripping off body tags?

Comment: Artefact, try with the code you have suggested this page: 
http://www.temple.edu/cs/web/sampleweb.html

I got some errors:
Warning: simplexml_import_dom() [function.simplexml-import-dom]: Invalid Nodetype to import

Comment: @Ric Good point, the second snippet may not work. The question is, what do you need this for? Manipulating the DOM structure doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: Basically try to load ANY possible well/mal/formed web page.... once loaded strip out content between BODY tags; into a string, would do.

Comment: Forgot to mention: keep all the HTML tags in the body!

Comment: Basically wiping out what's before and after the BODY tags, wiping them out as well.
- Keeping the correct charset
- allowing management of ALSO japanese/chinese charsets